# In Objective-C, if @property and @synthesize will add getter and setter, why not just make an instance variable public?

Tags: objective-c

In Objective-C, we can add `@property` and `@synthesize` to create a property -- like an instance variable with getter and setter which are public to the users of this class.

In this case, isn't it just the same as declaring an instance variable and making it public?  Then there won't be the overhead of calling the getter and setter as methods.  There might be a chance that we might put in validation for the setter, such as limiting a number to be between 0 and 100, but other than that, won't a public instance variable just achieve the same thing, and faster?

Comment: No, it isn't the same as declaring instance variables public, because you get key value coding and observing for free with properties. You can also specify various attributes to properties, like readonly, or attributes related to memory management.

Comment: so property is more versatile and convenient?  But what if we just need a single thing, such as a count, or color, and we know we don't need the fancy stuff, won't it make the program faster?

Comment: Performance is not a problem. Accessor methods and properties give you encapsulation which gives you a certain amount of flexibility. You may wish to cache the result of a property/getter or do some kind of internal magic to calculate its value. If you expose the instance variable directly, you cannot do this because existing code will break.

Comment: @peter KVC is also free with ivars.

Comment: @GrahamLee: oh, ok! :-) What about KVO?

Comment: properties also play well with Core Data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you're only using the accessors generated by `@synthesize`, they get you several benefits:

1. **Memory management:** generated setters retain the new value for a `(retain)` property. If you try to access an object ivar directly from outside the class, you don't know whether the class might retain it. (This is less of an issue under ARC, but still important.)
2. **Threadsafe access:** generated accessors are atomic by default, so you don't have to worry about race conditions accessing the property from multiple threads.
3. **Key-Value Coding & Observation:** KVC provides convenient access to your properties in various scenarios. You can use KVC when setting up predicates (say, for filtering a collection of your objects), or use key paths for getting at properties in collections (say, a dictionary containing objects of your class). KVO lets other parts of your program automatically respond to changes in a property's value -- this is used a lot with Cocoa Bindings on the Mac, where you can have a control bound to the value of a property, and also used in Core Data on both platforms.

In addition to all this, properties provide encapsulation. Other objects (clients) using an instance of your class don't have to know whether you're using the generated accessors -- you can create your own accessors that do other useful stuff without client code needing changes. At some point, you may decide your class needs to react to an externally made change to one of its ivars: if you're using accessors already, you only need to change them, rather than make your clients start using them. Or Apple can improve the generated accessors with better performance or new features in a future OS version, and neither the rest of your class' code nor its clients need changes.

Answer (score 3):

**Overhead Is Not a Real Issue**

To answer your last question, yes there will be overhead—but the overhead of pushing one more frame and popping it off the stack is negligible, especially considering the power of modern processors. If you are that concerned with performance you should profile your application and decide where actual problems are—I guarantee you you'll find better places to optimize than removing a few accessors.

**It's Good Design**

Encapsulating your private members and protecting them with accessors and mutators is simply a fundamental principle of good software design: it makes your software easier to maintain, debug, and extend. You might ask the same question about any other language: for example why not just make all fields public in your Java classes? (except for a language like Ruby, I suppose, which make it impossible to expose instance variables). The bottom line is that certain software design practices are in place because as your software grows larger and larger, you will be saving yourself from a veritable hell.

**Lazy Loading**

Validation in setters is one possibility, but there's more you can do than that. You can override your getters to implement lazy loading. For example, say you have a class that has to load some fields from a file or database. Traditionally this is done at initialization. However, it might be possible that not all fields will actually be used by whoever is instantiating the object, so instead you wait to initialize those members until it's requested via the getter. This cleans up initialization and can be a more efficient use of processing time.

**Helps Avoid Retain Cycles in ARC**

Finally, properties make it easier to avoid retain loops with blocks under ARC. The problem with ivars is that when you access them, you are implicitly referencing self. So, when you say:

```
_foo = 7;
```

what you're really saying is

```
self->_foo = 7;
```

So say you have the following:

```
[self doSomethingWithABlock:^{
    _foo = 7;
}];
```

You've now got yourself a retain cycle. What you need is a weak pointer.

```
__block __weak id weakSelf = self;
[self doSomethingWithABlock:^{
    weakSelf->_foo = 7;
}];
```

Now, obviously this is still a problem with setters and getters, however you are less likely to forget to use weakSelf since you have to explicity call self.property, whereas ivars are referenced by self implicitly. The static analayzer will help you pick this problem up if you're using properties.

Answer (score 1):

`@property` is a published fact. It tells other classes that they can get, and maybe set, a property of the class. Properties are not variables, they are literally what the word says. For example, `count` is a property of an `NSArray`. Is it necessarily an instance variable? No. And there's no reason why you should care whether it is.

`@synthesize` creates a default getter, setter and instance variable unless you've defined any of those things yourself. It's an implementation specific. It's how your class chooses to satisfy its contractual obligation to provide the property. It's just one way of providing a property, and you can change your implementation at any time without telling anyone else about it.

So why not expose instance variables instead of providing getters and setters? Because that binds your hands on the implementation of the class. It makes other acts rely on the specific way it has been coded rather than merely the interface you've chosen to publish for it. That quickly creates fragile and inter-dependent code that will break. It's anathema to object-oriented programming.

Comment: can the user of the class keep on using `foo.count = 12` and `n = foo.count` and not know whether it is public instance variable or a property?  (so the implementation is still kept unknown to the outside world).  Although in this case, `foo.setCount` cannot be used.

Comment: The user can continue to use the property `count` irrespective of how the class implements it — whether the class uses `@synthesize` and no custom getter and setter to bind the property straight to an instance variable or it does something more complicated like working it out dynamically or working it out and caching it, or caching it only unless and until a low memory warning occurs or whatever. Note that `foo.count` is not a valid way to access an instance variable in Objective-C and even if it were, it would generate different code from a getter/setter, giving you fragility.

Answer (score 1):

Because one would normally be interested in encapsulation and hiding data and implementations. It is easier to maintain; You have to change *one* implementation, rather than *all*. Implementation details are hidden from the client. Also, the client shouldn't have to think about whether the class is a derived class.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct... for a few very limited cases.  Properties are horrible in terms of CPU cycle performance when they are used in the inner loops of pixel, image and real-time audio DSP (etc.) code.  For less frequent uses, they bring a lot of benefits in terms of readable maintainable reusable code.

Answer (score 0):

@property and @synthesize is set are getting getter and setter methods

other usage is you can use the that variable in other classes also

if you want to use the variable as instance variable and your custom getter  and setter methods you can do but some times when you set the value for variable and while retrieving value of variable sometimes will become zombie which may cause crash of your app.

so the property will tell operating system not to release object till you deallocate your object of class,
 hope it helps